# copy range despite variable containing wrong value

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA macro to combine the information from two spreadsheets into one.
The copy-procedure is based on whether the value in a cell is >= 4. The procedure generally works, but it also copies the header despite the fact that the value is clearly a string and not an integer.
When I use code-stepping, it even shows me that the variable contains the string of the header and the range is copied nonetheless.

```
intColumn = 11  'these Variables define the column and row in which the compared value is found*
intRow = 8 

intCounter = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wksDataSource.Range("A1:A60000")) 
Zae3 = 0
For Zae4 = 1 To intCounter
  
    intCompareValue = wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, intColumn) 
    If intCompareValue >= 4 Then
     
        wksDataSource.Range(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 8), wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 8)).Copy 
        wksZielTabelle.Cells(intRow + Zae3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        
        wksDataSource.Range(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 1), wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 2)).Copy 
        wksZielTabelle.Cells(intRow + Zae3, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        
        wksDataSource.Range(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 11), wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 11)).Copy 
        wksZielTabelle.Cells(intRow + Zae3, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                
        Zae3 = Zae3 + 1
    End If
Next Zae4
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which string do you have? What's the result of `intCompareValue >= 4` for that string (in the immediate window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing of

```
 If intCompareValue >= 4 Then
```

with

```
 If IsNumeric(intCompareValue) And intCompareValue >= 4 Then
```

Comment: Massive thanks! that did it! now It doesnt copy the header.

Comment: @Questionairee: Glad I could help! But it is good to create the habit to properly declare all used variable. Otherwise, you may face bigger debugging problems if your code become more complex...

Comment: couldn't agree more. I try to be more thorough - then again i am just dusting of my reaaaaallly rusty VBA "knowledge"

Answer (score 0):

This piece should skip the non number values. But I'd declare the `intCompareValue` as a `Long` type to be sure later.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    intColumn = 11  'these Variables define the column and row in which the compared value is found*
    intRow = 8
    
    intCounter = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wksDataSource.Range("A1:A60000"))
    Zae3 = 0
    For Zae4 = 1 To intCounter
        If Not IsNumeric(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, intColumn)) Then GoTo NextValue
        intCompareValue = wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, intColumn)
        If intCompareValue >= 4 Then
         
            wksDataSource.Range(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 8), wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 8)).Copy
            wksZielTabelle.Cells(intRow + Zae3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            
            wksDataSource.Range(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 1), wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 2)).Copy
            wksZielTabelle.Cells(intRow + Zae3, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            
            wksDataSource.Range(wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 11), wksDataSource.Cells(intRow + Zae4, 11)).Copy
            wksZielTabelle.Cells(intRow + Zae3, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
                    
            Zae3 = Zae3 + 1
        End If
NextValue:
    Next Zae4

End Sub
```

Comment: If you write `Option Explicit` in your answer, you should put the variable declarations also in your code. That said: You probably mean `IsNumeric`?  This will, by the way, also return `True` if a cell contains the *string* `5` - or a date.

Comment: this looks like a lovely solution. I tried declaring ''' intCompareValue''' as an interger since only integers are being compared to, but i got an "incompatible type" error.

Comment: @FunThomas already corrected the `IsNumber`thought if there are numbers stored as text that should be for the OP top handle. The `Option Explicit` comes always on my answers sorry... it comes by default in my editor.

Comment: @Questionairee did you `Dim intCompareValue As Integer`? Though you can use `Long` because in vba an integer is a trunked Long.

Comment: @Damian yea, that was excatly what i did.

Comment: @Questionairee you are getting that error when assigning a value to the variable?

Comment: @Damian I am sorry, i should clarify. What I meant was that i get an error when executing the macro.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible, happens the same changing to `Long`?